# How to detect user inputting data into a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that a user enters/manages data in. They will insert rows, maybe copy rows and then input data.

There is a column, that holds MembID values, and the values for this are assigned when user clicks button to run a macro.

Every now and again the macro detects that it has duplicate values in the column and I am struggling to see how this could be possible and suspect that the user is manually entering values in the column.

I would like to be able to detect if they are entering data into a cell in that column. Any detection method needs to be able ignore changes made to the column by the macro! Is this possible to do?

Comment: Excel is not really suited for this, but you may give the Worksheet_Change event handler a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do 90+% of what I needed with the following code.....

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim intersection As Range
Dim ThisCell As String
Dim iRowFirst As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim sMessage As String
Dim iNoRows As Integer
Dim iMembColMembID As Integer
Dim iMembHeaderRow As Integer

' Find Column headings for "Membership" sheet
iMembHeaderRow = 1

Call FindHeader("Membership", iMembColMembID, iMembHeaderRow, "MembID")

Set intersection = Intersect(target, Range(Cells(1, iMembColMembID), Cells(2000, iMembColMembID)))

If Not intersection Is Nothing Then
    iRowFirst = target.Row
    iNoRows = target.Rows.Count

    sMessage = ""

    For iRow = iRowFirst To iRowFirst + iNoRows - 1
        ThisCell = Cells(iRow, iMembColMembID)

        If ThisCell <> "" Then
            If sMessage = "" Then
                sMessage = "The value for MembID has been changed for following row(s): "
            End If
            sMessage = sMessage & iRow & " "
        End If
    Next iRow
    If sMessage <> "" Then
        MsgBox sMessage
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I also put Application.EnableEvents.False at start of macro that adds new MembID values and then reenabled it at end of macro.

This detects the user adding data to the MembID column.

The only odd things are that if you copy/insert a number of rows then you will get 2 messages as the macro is triggered twice. Also, it will trigger if you delete a row.

But, in the grand scheme of things, then I can live with that!